# Convert comma-separated list of values into a single comma-separated string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, converters

How to convert this:

```
('xxx','yyy','zzz')
```

Into this:

```
('xxx,yyy,zzz')
```

Using T-SQL?

Comment: Where does this first value come from? Is it *a string*?

Comment: As a *set* of parameters? I don't understand. How do you pass a *set* of parameters to SQL Server and expect it to interpret it as a single string?

Comment: it is a set of input parameters - type nvarchar(30)

Comment: So `@param1 = 'xxx', @param2 = 'yyy'`, etc.? If so, then *stop* doing that. Use [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: Yep that is what I want to do :), convert these separate parameters into a coma separated string – i.e. concatenate them in a smart manner by inserting comas in between :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(32) = '''xxx'',''yyy'',''zzz''';
SELECT REPLACE(@x, ''',''', ',');
```

If all you want to do is concatenate then you can do:

```
SELECT @param1 + ',' + @param2 + ',' ... + @param30;
```

However that is just silly IMHO. This is like washing each of your socks separately.

I have to question what you're going to do with the value now... if these are separate entities why are they comma-separated in the first place? Perhaps you should look into [table-valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) instead of this comma-separated values nonsense, then you can use the values in a set-based way right from the start.

Comment: Em.. ok… it is not that simple. I generate queries on fly using templates and template values. Some of the template values are coming from different data-sources and are combined together via code. Final script looks something like this: “Select A,B,C from TableA where A in (‘xxx’,’yyy’,’zzz’)”. In most of the cases it is more than enough.

Comment: But sometimes we need to do something like: “Select * from TableB where B = ‘xxx,yyy,zzz’”

Comment: So in order not to change the logic that generates the script I’m looking for a way to concatenate those “paramters” on fly at the SQL server side.

Comment: if that makes any sense :)

Comment: @BashirMagomedov: Surely that's exactly what Aaron's second query does?

Comment: @Bashir if TableB stores `'xxx,yyy,zzz'` then either TableB is poorly designed or you should just pass the parameter `'xxx,yyy,zzz'` and then matching is not a problem. If you need partial matches then you are going to be fighting this poor design choice for the lifetime of the application, and I strongly recommend you stop storing data this way. If `xxx` and `yyy` are independent pieces of data, PLEASE stop munging them together and storing them together.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Totally agree. This is not our database we can’t anyhow influence it’s design. We just need to query it. It is a cumbersome piece of something you can hardly describe in a positive way. It has many tables with repetitive data, relations are not always clear, sometimes it is even EAV and XML :) We just have to live with it :(

Comment: Also have fun when someone decides 30 parameters aren't enough and you need to pass 100 or 500. Yikes.

Comment: @MarkBannister Not exactly, I am afraid. This assumes that I have a real finite number of parameters… but it is not the case. Sorry for the confusion. It is indeed confusing.

Comment: @Bashir you need to phrase your original question a lot more clearly. See all the details we've had to teeth-pull here? They should have all been in the question before anyone else had a chance to even read it.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I would rather mark it for deletion as it doesn’t contribute to the community ;(. I think I’ll have to handle such cases (the ones that require “concatenation”) separately and generate proper script for them rather than trying to do it on fly. Thank you anyway for your help. Our discussion helped me a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

by concatenating the values (*which means individual columns*)?

```
SELECT (col1 + ',' + col2+ ',' + col3) 
FROM   tableName
```

Comment: set of parameters? maybe @AaronBertrand 's answer will help you on this case.